# How to generate random vertices that form tetrahedrons?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, multidimensional-array, geometry

I am trying to develop a random tetrahedron generator that can take a list of four coordinates and produce a tetrahedron. Currently, I am only able to plot a tetrahedron using four pre-determined points. Here is the code I have as of now:

```
def rand_tetrahedron_generator(bounds, min_len, max_len):
    """
    bounds: List - max length in each dimension
    min_len: int - minimum length of tetrahedron
    max_len: int - maximum length of tetrahedron
    """
    assert len(bounds) == 3
    assert min_len <= max_len
    max_len = min(max_len, bounds[0], bounds[1], bounds[2])
    bounds = np.array(bounds)
    p1 = np.random.randint(low=0, high=bounds, size=3)
    p2 = np.random.randint(low=0, high=bounds - min_len, size=3)
    p3 = np.random.randint(low=0, high=p1+p2, size=3)
    p4 = np.random.randint(low=0, high=p1+p2, size=3)
    points = np.array([p1,p2,p3,p4])
    center = np.mean(points, axis=0)
    x, y, z = (np.indices((60, 60, 60))-np.array([20,25,25]).reshape(-1,1,1,1))/8
    mx = midpoints(x)
    my = midpoints(y)
    mz = midpoints(z)
    conditions = []
    for p1,p2,p3 in itertools.combinations(points, 3):
        a, n = surface_normal_form(p1,p2,p3)
        conditions.append((mx-a[0])*n[0]+(my-a[1])*n[1]+(mz-a[2])*n[2] <= 0)
    simplex = conditions[0] & conditions[1] & conditions[2] & conditions[3]
    return simplex
    
def surface_normal_form(a,b,c):
    v = b-a
    w = c-b
    n = np.cross(v,w)
    #normal needs to point out
    if (center-a)@n > 0:
         n *= -1
    return a, n

def midpoints(x):
    sl = ()
    for i in range(x.ndim):
        x = (x[sl + np.index_exp[:-1]] + x[sl + np.index_exp[1:]]) / 2.0
        sl += np.index_exp[:]
    return x
```

I believe that the way I generate p1, p2, p3, and p4 is incorrect because the function sometimes generates points that are unable to form a tetrahedron. I would greatly appreciate any advice on how to solve this issue. I have also attached an image of the final result I am looking for.
[image: Example Tetrahedron Plot]

Comment: Any four (non-coplanar) points in 3 dimensions can form a tetrahedron.  If you're having trouble some of the time, I would expect that to have to do with orientations.  I would check all your code dealing with normal vectors and make sure that all normal vectors are oriented properly.  That being said, you are picking integer points so coplanarity is possible.  If you're worried about your point generation process, print them out in your function and also split that part of the code off from the plotting portion.

Comment: Pick a random point P1.   Pick a second random point P2 that isn't coincident with P1.   Next, pick a third point P3 disjoint from the line through P1 and P2; you can check that P3 is disjoint by taking the cross product of P1->P2 and P1->P3, and P3 is good if the cross product is non-0.   Finally, pick a fourth point P4 that does not lie in the plane P1, P2, P3, which you can do by the cross product of P1->P2 and P1->P3, which yields the normal vector to the P1, P2, P3 plane.